# Bootstrap Grid - issue getting desired spacing/padding between text and images within divs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, grid-layout

I'm trying to create a simple bootstrap grid with some data results.  The spacing the first header (web-based review) and reported text (e.g., 211 -> new line "total projects identified) is too much.  It looks a bit awkward.  Basically, I want to eliminate the extra line break/spaces.  The spacing between "Interviews" and the image below is good, however when I tried playing around with "Web-based review" to make it look similar, everything went to hell.

For clarify, I've attached an image to show what I'd like.

Bottom line, I want to fix (1) the spacing between the "Web-based Review" header and the image below it and (2) the numbers in large text and the text below.

Desired Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGyqo.jpg 
Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/tenebris_silentio/pen/YzqRQOv

```js
var ultimateColors = [
        ['rgb(0, 25, 51)', 'rgb(0, 76, 153)']
      ];

      var data = [{
        values: [50, 50],
        labels: ['<b>Coded</b>', '<b>Uncoded</b>'],
        text: ["<b> Description</b>: Projects that have been coded", '<b>Description</b>: Projects that have not yet been coded'],
        textinfo: 'percent',
        domain: {column: 0},
        name: 'Sources',
        marker: {
          colors: ultimateColors[0]
        },
        hoverinfo: 'label+percent+desc+text',


        type: 'pie'
      }];

      var layout = {
        title: '',
        annotations: [
          {
            font: {
              size: 17
            },
            showarrow: false,
            text: '',
            x: 0.5,
            y: 0.5
          },


        ],
        height: 380,
        width: 550,
        showlegend: false,
        grid: {rows: 1, columns: 1}
      };

      Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```css
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif}
.mySlides {display: none}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <h3>Web-based Review</h3> <img src="https://i.ibb.co/4JRWPNX/reviewpic.jpg" width="275" height="275"  align="left">
       <br><br>  <p class="w3-justify"><p style="font-size:30px">211</p>total projects identified

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <div id='myDiv'> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <h3>Interviews</h3> <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Cbvz20q/interviewpic.jpg" width="275" height="275"  align="left">
       <br><br>  <p class="w3-justify"><p style="font-size:30px">9</p>interviews completed<br><br><p style="font-size:30px">46</p> operational interviews identified

    </div>

      10 of 20 projects have been coded.
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your heading the reason it's not closer to your image is there is a lot of white space above the computer. You should resize image with less white space, but if you cannot you can use `transform: translateY()` to get a similar effect.

For the numbers, a `p` tag comes with margin from most browser base styling and bootstrap's reboot css as well. You can adjust the structure and use `span` with classes and line breaks to make it better. Code included:

```js
var ultimateColors = [
  ['rgb(0, 25, 51)', 'rgb(0, 76, 153)']
];

var data = [{
  values: [50, 50],
  labels: ['<b>Coded</b>', '<b>Uncoded</b>'],
  text: ["<b> Description</b>: Projects that have been coded", '<b>Description</b>: Projects that have not yet been coded'],
  textinfo: 'percent',
  domain: {
    column: 0
  },
  name: 'Sources',
  marker: {
    colors: ultimateColors[0]
  },
  hoverinfo: 'label+percent+desc+text',


  type: 'pie'
}];

var layout = {
  title: '',
  annotations: [{
      font: {
        size: 17
      },
      showarrow: false,
      text: '',
      x: 0.5,
      y: 0.5
    },


  ],
  height: 380,
  width: 550,
  showlegend: false,
  grid: {
    rows: 1,
    columns: 1
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif
}

.mySlides {
  display: none
}

span.projectNumber {
  font-size: 30px
}


/* I recommend instead of using below code to resize image with less white space */
h3.wbrHeader {
  transform: translateY(50px);
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <h3 class="wbrHeader">Web-based Review</h3> <img src="https://i.ibb.co/4JRWPNX/reviewpic.jpg" width="275" height="275" align="left">
      <br><br>
      <p class="w3-justify">
        <p><span class="projectNumber">211</span><br>total projects identified</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <div id='myDiv'> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <h3>Interviews</h3> <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Cbvz20q/interviewpic.jpg" width="275" height="275" align="left">
      <br><br>
      <p class="w3-justify">
        <p><span class="projectNumber">9</span><br>interviews completed</p><br><br>
        <p><span class="projectNumber">46</span><br>operational interviews identified</p>
    </div>

    10 of 20 projects have been coded.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, this was a very thorough and helpful explanation that got the job done.  The span part was key for me. Thank you.